# Create Goggle OAuth credentials through API?

Tags: google-api, terraform, google-oauth

Is there any way to create credentials(https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) through some api?

Ideally I should be able to do it with terraform.

I checked https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/identity_platform_oauth_idp_config.html but it looks like something different

Answer (score 2):

No there is no API for creating credentials programmatic these credentials must be created manually though the console.